# Django ForeignKey with null=True, inner join, and left outer join

Tags: django, left-join, inner-join

Let's say I have two Django models Person and Company as follows: -

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Person(models.Model):
    last_name = models.CharField(blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField()
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, blank=True)
```

A Person may or may not belong to a Company.

I am using MySQL. I want all Persons that do not belong to any Company, that is, Persons where company is null.

If I do `Person.objects.filter(company__isnull=True)` I get an SQL which is essentially: -

`SELECT * FROM PersonTable LEFT OUTER JOIN AgencyTable ON (PersonTable.company_id = AgencyTable.id) WHERE AgencyTable.id IS NULL`

How do I go about achieving the following SQL: -

`SELECT * FROM PersonTable INNER JOIN AgencyTable ON (PersonTable.company_id = AgencyTable.id) WHERE AgencyTable.id IS NULL`

From what I gather from reading up the Django Users mailing list, this used to be the behavior before QuerySet Refactor.

EDIT -- Now I see the blasphemy of my question!

What I want to say is I simply want to do

`SELECT * FROM PersonTable WHERE PersonTable.company_id IS NULL`

Comment: Well, if this is not making sense to you, this is actually a 'base' query that gets INNER JOINed with other queries, and this leads to weird, repetitive results.

Comment: This question is really a result of a mental block.

Answer (score 15):

Well, this question is old, and soon the patch will be in Django. But for the brief meantime, the answer is in http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10790:

> Workaround: Instead of
>
> `Person.objects.filter(company=None)`
>
> use
>
> `Person.objects.exclude(company__isnull=False)`

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as:

```
Person.objects.filter(company_id__isnull=True)
```

Note the use of `company_id` which is the default integer field created by the ForeignKey

**Edit**

Sorry, I haven't actively used django since 0.9.5. Either I'm thinking of pre-1.0 behavior, or I'm muddling up sqlalchemy and Django ORM. In either case, as the comments stated, the above appears to not work.

It looks like the only way to get the query you want in current django is to use the `.extra` query parameter, which comes with a whole list of caveats.

```
Person.objects.extra(where=['company_id IS NULL'])
```

Note that this may not be portable to all DB's, and it may not work combined with filter(), and any number of possible issues. I would recommend not using this throughout your code, and instead moving it to a classmethod on Person like:

```
 @classmethod
 def list_unaffiliated_people(cls):
    return cls.objects.extra(where=['company_id IS NULL'])
```

Alternately, just use the proper ORM query syntax and suck up the possible performance hit (have you actually benchmarked the more complicated query to see that it's any slower?)

Comment: Tried it out in the shell, it gives me FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'company_id' into field. Choices are: company, first_name, last_name

Comment: Hrm. I thought that it was possible to query on the key like that. I guess it's back to the drawing board on that one.

Comment: That's not possible. `company__id__isnull` would be valid, but would generate pretty much the same SQL.

Comment: @ayaz, Crast was referring to company_id (single underscore). I think you are referring to company__id (double underscore)

Comment: @chefsmart: That's correct. I wanted to point out that the way `company_id` is referenced in a QuerySet method is not only going to not work but also give an error.

Answer (score 0):

Django will treat `NULL` as Python's `None` object so:

```
Person.objects.filter(company = None)
```

Comment: This also gives the same SQL. I guess the way Django is doing it is not that bad after all. I will focus on how I can improve my other lookups and see if I can solve my problem.